Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS - mouse cursor stuck in drag mode
I have been having the good old mouse cursor stuck in drag mode issue. So, it started happening 1-2 days ago and the frequency of it is every 1-2 hours after a fresh reboot. First, the mouse left click starts behaving strange like opening new tabs on browser and not responding to clicks and then keyboard also get unresponsive. First I was using the main power button to reboot the system since I couldn't even open the Terminal. Then, I found if I unplug my HDMI cable from laptop-monitor screen, I can open some terminal and then do reboot. Note, if I do click on something else other than terminal the same issue starts, so I have this chance to run any command I want which I usually do a reboot. What I have tried is:

Ran apt update && apt upgrade
Updating Windows Action Key to Alt in the Tweaks tool
Uninstalled Tweaks tool (I installed it few months back)
Ran pkill nautilus based on another thread I saw
Ran gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "'<Alt>'" based on this answer
It even happens when I disconnect my laptop from the monitor screen.

Here is the result from xinput
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Mouse                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Keyboard              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN067C:00 04F3:31F9 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN067C:00 04F3:31F9 Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logi M750 Mouse                           id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device                       id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ sof-hda-dsp Headphone                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logi K950                                 id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what can be done? as this is extremely annoying and hard to workaround

Sounds like a stuck key.  Try pressing all the shift keys on the keyboard (ctrl alt shift windows compose, etc.) so that the GUI gets a key release event for each key.  If this fixes it, next step is to figure out who is sending the key down event.  HDMI and your actual keyboard are two possibilities, there are others.

I did press all these keys once the issue started coming and seems like the "Windows" key did some trick temporarily but it again gets unresponsive once I click on any icon on the Dock or even somewhere on the browser window.

Something probably is still sending key down events for that key.

This smells like a hardware issue.  Maybe try unplugging and replugging all your usb devices to cold reset them.  HDMI can include usb, but I've never seen that actually used.

Thanks for getting back. I will try that out and will update. As a temporary fix, once the freeze happens I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then unlock it. It doesn't discard my current work and I don't have to restart.
